# how to achieve object literals in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class which has named constructor and I want to pass variable and eval the result as a class variable how can I achieve it like in javascript we have object literals and eval
I'm getting the data from server like [{path: 'fullName', msg: "Field is Required" }, {...}]
below is the example:

```
class Test{
   String fullName;
   
   Test({this.fullName});

}

Map ob = {fullName: "someAnotherName", another:another};
var t = Test(ob); //how to achieve this line

var varaible = "fullName";
t.[variable]; //how to achieve this line
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to write a named `fromJson` factory constructor which accpets a `Map<String, dyanmic>` as an argument which is the json data you will pass to it.
For the code you provided it would be like:

```dart
class Test{
   String fullName;
   
   Test({this.fullName});

   factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return Test(
         fullName: json['fullName'],
      );
   }
}

Map ob = {fullName: "someAnotherName", another:another};
var t = Test.fromJson(ob);
t.fullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your **ob** is a Map you can get **fullname** by writing
`var name = ob['fullName']` or this way

```
var fullName = 'fullName';
var name = ob[fullName];
```

Both should contain **someAnotherName**